# Removal of HTTP webrequest elements

Tags: .net, vb.net, soap, webrequest, wse3.0

I'm looking to remove certain elements from a `HTTPWebRequest` I have attached the elements I need to remove in an image (elements are coloured red):

[image]

I've tried:

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
```

for one of the elements but to no avail
I've also tried:

```
webRequest.Headers.Remove(HttpRequestHeader.Connection)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

here is my code:

```
    Dim content As blah.Content = New blah.Content
    Dim inputguid As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
    Dim service As blah.WebService = New blah.WebService
    Dim str As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim payload As blah.Payload = New blah.Payload
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
    'payload
    str.LoadXml(xmlstr)

    'manifest
    service.payloadManifest = New blah.PayloadManifest
    service.payloadManifest.manifest = New blah.Manifest() {New blah.Manifest}
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).element = "GetVehicleServiceHistory"
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).namespaceURI = "http://www.starstandards.org/STAR"
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).contentID = "Content0"
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).version = "2.01"
    service.SoapVersion = SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11
    service.UserAgent = "VendorName"

    payload.content = New blah.Content() {content}
    ReDim Preserve payload.content(0)
    payload.content(0).Any = str.DocumentElement
    payload.content(0).id = "Content0"

    service.Timeout = -1
    service.Url = "http://localhost:8080"
    service.ProcessMessage(payload)
```

and then within the reference.vb of my webservice:

```
    Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal uri As Uri) As WebRequest
        Dim webRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(MyBase.GetWebRequest(uri), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim sp As ServicePoint
        sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(New Uri(Me.Url))
        sp.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0
        webRequest.Headers.Remove(HttpRequestHeader.Connection)
        webRequest.KeepAlive = False
        webRequest.Timeout = 100000
        webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 100000

        Return webRequest
    End Function
```

Comment: can you post the whole code of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hint#1: stop using WSE. It's very obsolete.

Comment: Also, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Why do you believe you need to change those headers? Though it does look like the wrong quotation marks are used around one of the SOAPAction header values.

Comment: i have sorted this.. did not need to change soap action header value

Answer (score 1):

You would like to get rid of some of the more detailed headers from your HTTP message?
One easy thing you can do would be this:

```
webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10
```

Several of those headers aren't in the 1.0 version of HTTP and only exist in the 1.1 version ([Key Differences](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html)), so downgrading to the 1.0 version should take care of a lot of those 'extra headers' for you.

If you want to get rid of the Content-Length header, then I'm pretty sure you'll have to switch from POST to GET.  If you're doing a POST, then Content-Length is typically required!

If that just doesn't do it for you then you'll have to go the final step and stop using HttpWebRequest (which is doing a lot of the HTTP work for you) and just do a plain TCP connection (perhaps with the [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) class?) and specify the exact HTTP message you want to send.  It's a lot more work, but that's likely to be the only way to send a very specific message where you control all the HTTP headers being used.

Hope that helps!